# laravel random matching values from 2 arrays

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 arrays:
one for users and other one to locations
how can I random between users array and locations array
For example:

locations array :

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4291 ▼
  #items: array:20 [▼
    0 => {#4312 ▶}
    1 => {#4318 ▶}
    2 => {#4313 ▶}
    3 => {#4315 ▶}
    4 => {#4316 ▶}
    5 => {#4319 ▶}
    6 => {#4320 ▶}
    7 => {#4321 ▶}
    8 => {#4322 ▶}
    9 => {#4323 ▶}
    10 => {#4324 ▶}
    11 => {#4325 ▶}
    12 => {#4326 ▶}
    13 => {#4327 ▶}
    14 => {#4328 ▶}
    15 => {#4329 ▶}
    16 => {#4330 ▶}
    17 => {#4331 ▶}
    18 => {#4332 ▶}
    19 => {#4333 ▼
      +"business_location_id": 46
      +"business_location_name": "Khan El-Moaz"
    }
  ]
}
```

and users array:

```
array:2 [▼
  167 => "167"
  199 => "199"
]
```

Now I need to get random values from the 2 arrays together like this

```
[▼
  {
        "user_id": "167",
        "location_id": "20"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "199",
        "location_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "150",
        "location_id": "5"
    },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where, specifically, are you stuck? Please make an attempt to solve this yourself (or at least specify what you've tried, if anything), then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75367207/edit) with more details. Please remember that on Stackoverflow, you're expected to make an attempt to solve your own issue before asking for help 

Comment: Also, be aware that one of those is a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections), which has additional functionality that a basic array in PHP does not.

Comment: @TimLewis please check my answer , it has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by this steps:
First:  convert the collection to array

```
$business_locations = $results->toArray();
```

then make foreach on one of the aaray and get random key from the second array and create new array with data from first and second array then remove the use data from the array

```
$final_result = [];
        
        foreach($users as $user)
        {

            $randomItems = array_rand($business_locations,1);
            $collection = collect($final_result);
            
            if(!$collection->contains('location_id', $business_locations[$randomItems]->business_location_id))
            {
                array_push($final_result, (object)[
                    'user_id' => $user[user_id],
                    'user_name' => $user[user_name],
                    
                    'location_id' => $business_locations[$randomItems]->business_location_id,
                    'location_name' => $business_locations[$randomItems]->business_location_name,
                ]);
                
                array_splice($business_locations, $randomItems, 1);
            }
            
        }
```